# Finding y-intercept of the graph of f.

Tags: functions

> Let $f(x) = x^2 + x - 6$.
>
> a. Write down the $y$-intercept of the graph of $f$.

how do we figure this out? I know $f(x)$ means $y$, so do we use the quadratic formula? $x^2 + x - 6$.

> b. Solve $f(x) = 0$.

We plug $0$ into the $x$’s in the original formula, right?

Comment: You’ve got it exactly backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're being asked for the $y$-intercept of the graph, you're being asked where your graph crosses the $y$ axis - i.e. where $x = 0$. This is what you need for part $a)$.

For part $b)$, you're being asked where the graph crosses the $x$ axis, and this is where $y=0$ or alternatively where $f(x) = 0$. As such, you need to solve the equation $f(x) = 0$, for $x$.

Comment: so, for a, I put 0 in for the x’s in the function? And then b, I set the function to 0 and solve for x.

Comment: I got y = -6 and then I factored for b and got x = -3 and x = 2. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Sounds good to me! Well done. Hopefully you can remember this for future examples :)